# Повторная отправка формы

Tags: php, форма

При отладке php-кода в браузере нажимаю "Обновить" и постоянно вылетает окошко типа "Подтвердить повторную отправку формы?". А можно как-то без этого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без этого можно, но для этого нужно делать редирект на другую страницу по завершении обработки данных формы или отправлять их сразу на другой адрес (обработку данных формы вынести в отдельный скрипт).

Но лучше воспользоваться ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Обновление это такое себе повторение действий. Если Вы перед этим отправили форму то обновление предложит отправить её еще раз. Все логично.

Если Вам не удобно используйте. CTRL+L Enter.

CTRL+L - помещает курсор в адресную строку

Enter - заново загружает страницу

Comment: Спасибо, так я и думал, по-другому и быть не может. Я-то все-таки форму повторно отправляю