# убрать уведомление о повторной отправки форм в CHROME

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

убрать уведомление о повторной отправки форм в CHROME или автоматически соглашаться на отправку. [image: вот]

Comment: для этого надо правильно post оформлять, т.е. после обработки действия совершать редирект. Где-то был такой вопрос, это дубликат

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Повторная отправка формы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/180998/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b)